# Run Tensorflow and Pyspark Together in same program

Tags: apache-spark, tensorflow, pyspark

When I run a program with tensorflow an pyspark together with `spark-submit` `sample.py` it says no module named `tensorflow` but when I run activate tensorflow and run with python `sample.py` it says no module named pyspark.

```
import tensorflow as tf

import pyspark # only run after findspark.init()

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.sql('''select 'spark' as hello ''')

df.show()
```